# Can't install Windows 8 on a UEFI with GPT laptop?

Tags: windows-8, ssd, uefi, dell-inspiron, gpt

I had **Windows 8** (Single language) **pre-installed** on my new laptop ... and it has **lags**..i tried to make **refresh or reset** and it told me that **(The driver is locked)**

So i managed to make **a clean install** of windows 8 ... and when i proceed to click **custom install** .**. ( I didn't find any partition in the list )**

even **automatic repair** didn't work ... and it didn't find my **restore points** (as it didn't find the partitions.)

Now i **can't boot** in the system it gives me **(BSOD)**

**File: \BCD
Status: 0xc0000098
info: The boot configuration data file doesn't contain valid information for an operating system.**

I've tried to overcome this using **rescue boot cds** but it doesn't find any partition drivers.

I tried from **USB** too and it did the same.

I tried to **write the BCD files from scratch** .. as it mentioned **here**

https://neosmart.net/wiki/recovering-windows-bootloader/

but after restart **nothing happened** .. after that i found that it thought the usb is my partition (as it didn't recognise my partitions) **it considered the usb as my C driver**

**I made every thing** ... tried to make the partitions **active** through **CMD** .. But it didn't find the hard disc.

I managed to **repair** the **boot problem** using **Easy Recovery Essentials Pro for windows 8** ..

and I made **backup of my files** ...

but after the boot ... it gives me **a blue screen** that **my pc ran into a problem and needs to restart** ..

aftr restart .. it tells me **there is no boot device** !!

**Any suggestions ??**

**DELL Inspiron 15R 7520 Special Edition**

**Core i7, 8G RAM , 1TB HDD, 32 SSD, Windows 8**

Comment: You shouldn't have to write the BCD files by hand. Are you sure the installation disk has the required EFI files?

Comment: I didi't do that unless every method before had failed... 
Yea it has it ...

THE PROBLEM ... is that my pattitions are not recognised .. if i managed to make the system recoginse them ... i can solve the rest

Comment: Why are you not allowing Windows to create the require partitions?  If you are doing it by hand then you are doing something wrong.

Comment: There are 5 partitions there .. one of them has windows 8 ... neither windows 8 dvd nor any other repair cds could identify them.. if You know something please Help ... my files are there .. and im an engineerin' student .. and i badly need them

Comment: I strongly suggest you use a Live Linux environment to grab the files because it will be much easier for you, if you use the OEM's recovery disk to solve this problem.

Comment: the laptop equipped with no recovery disk .. could you mention a url to the live linux environment

Comment: [Knoppix](http://www.knoppix.org) is the original Linux Live CD/DVD. Go to the top right hand corner and click the English flag so you can read the page. The DVD download has more stuff but the CD should suffice.

Answer (score 2):

Thank You Guys ... **the  Easy Recovery Essentials Pro for windows 8** did the job.

I used the **Gparted utility** and **flaged C (OS) as boot** ... then i run **automatic repair** from the same disk ...

I rebooted then it goes for **a long boot process** ... so I **terminated** it and then booted the cd again and .. **unflaged** the  C ... made **Automatic Repair** .. and rebooted ..

**and every thing goes well ...**

**Thank You ..**